# Spring DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory dropping messages on JBoss EAP 7

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, jboss7.x, spring-jms, jta

I have the following Spring JMS factory configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "jmsListenerFactory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerFactory() throws Exception {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory container = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    container.setErrorHandler(new MqErrorHandler());
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    container.setConcurrency("5-10");
    return container;
}
```

Listener setup:

```
@JmsListener(destination = ACK_QUEUE, containerFactory = "jmsListenerFactory")
@Transactional
public void receive(String response) throws Exception {
    try {
        logger.debug(response);
        Msg ackNack = (Msg) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(response));
        ... and so on
        ... should acknowledge JMS and commit DB update
}
```

JTA Transaction Manager:

```
public JtaTransactionManager jbossTransactionManager() throws Exception {
    JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setTransactionManagerName("java:/TransactionManager");
    return transactionManager;
}
```

I have an Oracle database and a JMS connection factory resource included via JNDI, both XA compatible.

Problem is that some JMS messages are not making it to the listener. They are 100% provided to the queue but like they just "disappear". No logging or errors are reported in the logs even to TRACE level.

Nothing else is listening to this queue and similar transactions are getting processed successfully from the same queue. I cannot reproduce it in any guaranteed way and it is completely intermittent.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Run some sort of trace, e.g. Activity Trace, to see what is getting the messages off your queue.

Comment: @MoragHughson Activity Trace is an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lesson to be learned here is never to assume the following:

> "Nothing else is listening to this queue.."

There are ways to try and verify this:

1. Check how many processes currently have the queue open for INPUT:

   `DIS QL(QUEUENAME) IPPROCS`
2. Display all connections that have the queue currently open with `OPENOPTS` that include `MQOO_INPUT*`, this will show both IP address (if it is a client connection), and the application name (APPLTAG) presented by the client.

   `DIS CONN(*) TYPE(ALL) WHERE(OBJNAME EQ QUEUENAME)`
3. Both of the above only show a point in time view, if you are trying to find a app that is connecting reading messages from the queue and then disconnecting, then you may not see it.

   As @MoragHughson mentioned in a comment, start an activity trace and look for connections to this queue and see if the IPs/application names connecting are what is expected, this has the advantage that you can see over a period of time all of the things that have connected to the queue.

   Below is an example of one way to do this using the amqsevt from IBM MQ v9.1 or later and targeting a IBM MQ v9.0 or later queue manager (this relies on a opensource JSON processor called `jq`).  The example below will run until there is no activity for 5 minutes (300 seconds) or until a key is pressed (you can increase the time by increasing the `-w` value):

```sh
#Replace the string _REPLACE_WITH_QMGR_NAME_ with your queue manager name in both places.
#Replace the string _REPLACE_WITH_QUEUE_NAME_ with your queue name.

amqsevt -m _REPLACE_WITH_QMGR_NAME_ -t '$SYS/MQ/INFO/QMGR/_REPLACE_WITH_QMGR_NAME_/ActivityTrace/ConnectionId/#' -w 300 -o json | jq -r '
.eventData
| [.channelName, .channelType, .connectionName, .applName, .remoteProduct, .remoteVersion] as $x
| ( .activityTrace[]
    | select(.objectName == "_REPLACE_WITH_QUEUE_NAME_") | [.operationTime]
      + $x
      + [.operationId, .objectName, .resolvedQueueName, .reasonCode.value, .putDate, .putTime] )
| @csv
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved as messages were being silently consumed by DEV queue manager ... which was invalid configuration.

Comment: Glad you're all sorted - suggest you accept (press tick) on the answer from @JoshMc as it is an excellent and very useful answer for future readers.